# How to solve the following problem regarding the non increasing function $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

I have tried like this. Suppose $G(x)=\left(\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right)^2$. Then $G'(x)=2f(x)\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. From this how I can proceed?

Comment: @paul I don't think $g$ will usually be differentiable, right?

Answer (score 1):

$G'(x) \leq G'(0)=0$ for $x > 0$ since $G'$ is non-increasing. Hence $G$ itself is non-increasing for $x > 0$ which implies $0 \leq G(x) \leq G(0)=0$. Hence $G (x)=0$ for all $x >0$ which implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x>0$. Use a similar argument for $x <0$.